# BASE64Encoder is internal API and may be removed in future release

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I tried to solve this problem but I never come to a solution that would work for me. The problem is that I am getting warings about BASE64Encoder. Is there any other way to do this without the BASE64Encoder?

The code:

```
public static String Encrypt(String Data) throws Exception 
{
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal); //Here is the problem

    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String Decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception 
{
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData); //Another problem
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);

    return decryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception 
{
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    return key;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should now be using the Base64 Encoder and Decoder classes (from Java 8 onwards).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(final String... args) {
      try {
         // Encode using basic encoder
         String base64encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("TutorialsPoint?java8".getBytes("utf-8"));
         System.out.println("Base64 Encoded String (Basic) :" + base64encodedString);

         // Decode
         byte[] base64decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64encodedString);

         System.out.println("Original String: " + new String(base64decodedBytes, "utf-8"));
         base64encodedString = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString("TutorialsPoint?java8".getBytes("utf-8"));
         System.out.println("Base64 Encoded String (URL) :" + base64encodedString);

         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

         for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            stringBuilder.append(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
         }

         byte[] mimeBytes = stringBuilder.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
         String mimeEncodedString = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(mimeBytes);
         System.out.println("Base64 Encoded String (MIME) :" + mimeEncodedString);

      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         System.out.println("Error :" + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Code taken from [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_base64.htm).